# What exactly is "matrix sparsity" $s$?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, hhl-algorithm, terminology-and-notation

In many sources (like on Page 30 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08227)), I found that the complexity of the original Harrow Hassidim Lloyd is stated as $\mathcal{O}(\log (N) s^2 \kappa^2/\epsilon)$ where $s$ is said to be the "matrix sparsity". What is a precise definition of the term "matrix sparsity"? I couldn't find it stated anywhere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have the definitions in your paper [you link](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08227) page 12.
Simply said, it is a matrix with many 0s.
As an example take N = 16, and the polynomial function is just a simple function like 1.5*X,
then your matrix has at most 1.5*log(16,2)=6 non-zero entries per row.

[image: Definitions of sparsity]

If you prefer a visual, you have it [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~amchilds/talks/nsf15.pdf):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I believe the way they use it is as

> The maximum number of non-zero elements in any row.

Although that’s different to the way Wikipedia defines sparsity, which is essentially the average:

> the total number of non-zero elements divided by the number of elements.